# Calling a .vbs script from Excel VBA

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to call a .vbs script from a VBA code whenever needed? If possible then can you give me a sample code of how to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing VBScript file from Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238215/executing-vbscript-file-from-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: As it is a duplicate, I voted to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To run a file:

```
Shell "wscript c:\null\a.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

replacing `wscript` with `cscript` if the VBS wants to use the console.

Or you can add a reference to the *[Microsoft Script Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633(v=vs.60).aspx)* and interact with the VBScript runtime directly to execute VBS code, procedures etc;

```
Dim scr As ScriptControl: Set scr = New ScriptControl
scr.Language = "VBScript"
scr.AddCode "sub T: msgbox ""All Hail Cthulhu"": end sub"
scr.Run "T"
```

Comment: Hi Alex, i want to call a .vbs file from VBA... so how to do that? this was my question..Can you clarify your suggestion please?

Comment: Sub test()

Dim scr As ScriptControl: Set scr = New ScriptControl
scr.Language = "VBScript"
scr.AddCode "sub T: msgbox ""All Hail Cthulhu"": end sub"
scr.Run "T"

End Sub

Comment: getting error : Compiler error: "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: The `shell` line runs a vbs ... To avoid `User-defined type not defined` you must click **tools** -> **references** in the VBA IDE & tick *Microsoft Script Control 1.0*

Comment: Hello Alex, you are really helpful. Now i have one doubt.when i would call .vbs file from a vba code,then how the control return from vbs to vba code next line, when vbs script will finish its job?

Comment: Alex, would you mind adding one more detail to your answer? That the object may also be created using `set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")`, which is the only option in some environments.

Answer (score 10):

I only want to add to Alex' answer, that in some environments the object must be created in the following way:

```
set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
```

If Alex adds this to his answer, I will delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```vb
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
Shell "wscript " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\your.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `"""` if your path name contains a `-` For me the following solved this issue:

```
Shell "cscript """ & ActiveWorkbook.Path & """\your.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```