# Running VBA script file from excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to run a vbscript file from excel macro, can anyone please help.

```vb
Dim sFilename As String
sFilename = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\266720\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\Scripts\Script7-pa30.vbs"
sFilename.Run
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a .vbs script from Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133126/calling-a-vbs-script-from-excel-vba)

Comment: Currently, sFilename will look like `c:\foo\bar\c:\Users\266...` You are concatening two absolute paths

Answer (score -1):

Could be an issue with the space in your reference.

```
"C:\Users\266720\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\Scripts\Script7-pa30.vbs"
```

I would change the folder name to SAP_GUI and see how that works, or use double quotes around the whole line.

```
"""C:\Users\266720\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI" & "\Scripts\Script7-pa30.vbs"""
```

Comment: Windows manage spaces in paths. And this is not sent to a shell so a space should not matter