# Unable to run vbscript file due to access limit

Tags: html, excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to upload a file on HTML page, for which I need to run the vbascript saved on my desktop. But when I am executing the code its asking for admin permission and getting error as "Access Denied". So is there any way to run this file without but it should not break any policy and as I don't want to create any security issue.

Thanks in advance:)

```
Sub uploadFiles()

Dim ie As Object
Dim strFile As Variant
Dim strUploadFile As Variant
Dim objShell As Variant


 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.navigate "https://www.pdftoexcelconverter.net/"
 ie.Visible = True

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
strFile = "C:\Users\kiranm\Desktop\2019\FileUpload.vbs"  
strUploadFile = "C:\Users\kiranm\Desktop\2019\fl0005.pdf" 

Dim R_Shl As Double


Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   objShell.Run Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & strUploadFile & Chr(34)


ie.document.getElementsByName("Filedata")(0).Click
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)


End Sub
```

Comment: I tried: Shell "wscript.exe" & strFile & " " & strUploadFile
as well but error receiving " File not Found"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how
 `Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & strUploadFile & Chr(34)`
really looks like (this is from your code): `"C:\Users\kiranm\Desktop\2019\FileUpload.vbs"C:\Users\kiranm\Desktop\2019\fl0005.pdf"`
As you see, there are not enough double quotes and spaces.

And here is how
`"wscript.exe" & strFile & " " & strUploadFile`
look like (this is from your comment)
`wscript.exeC:\Users\kiranm\Desktop\2019\FileUpload.vbs C:\Users\kiranm\Desktop\2019\fl0005.pdf`

So, I would have tried to use this version:
`Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & strUploadFile & Chr(34)`
 in the code in post.

Comment: I tried this code but same error I am getting that is "file not found". have you test this code on your PC and is it works for you?

Comment: @kiranmamalwad I've pointed on obvious mistakes, posted it as an answer because comments are limited in text length and formatting. I suppose that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133126/calling-a-vbs-script-from-excel-vba) link will help you.