# Avoid blocking user interaction with form - Access VBA 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

This may seem like a very odd thing to do in VBA but I'm curious so hear me out. 
I created a procedure that moves an image across the screen when it's clicked. This works, albeit alright, but still - it works.

Here is the code:

```
'Start primitive animation
Private Sub imgBean_Click()

    'Limit for movement to right
    Dim coordinates, limit As Integer
    coordinates = 0
    limit = Form.Width

    Do While coordinates < limit

        coordinates = coordinates + 5

        'Move the image
        Me.imgBean.Move coordinates

        'Needed to add this to see the image move - updates the form
        Form.Repaint

    Loop

    Debug.Print "Coordinates " & coordinates
    Debug.Print limit

    'Reset the limit
    limit = 0

End Sub
```

As said before the code works - but while the image is moving the screen is frozen i.e. I can't close the form or interact with other components. (This is similar to blocking the UI thread in the Android environment - something that you never do!)

So is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

P.S. Setting the focus to the form makes the image sporadically appear and disappear.

Comment: Let's be honest there, Microsoft Access isn't especially recognize for his multitasking capabilities. I'm having the same problem with most my VBA applications (whether it's Access, Excel or Outlook).

Comment: @dnLL I know but thought I'd chance it :P

Comment: multi-threading isnt supported by excel

Comment: @mehow I'm not using Excel - I know it isn't supported in VBA so I'm looking into other means - came across something similar (to multithreading) which leverages VBScript, though not sure if it's appropriate for what I want - seems it's more suited to web scraping and stuff of that nature

Comment: sorry excel <-> access same thing. You can [simulate multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238215/how-to-call-vbscript-from-excel-macros) but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238215/how-to-call-vbscript-from-excel-macros) example will not suit you moving the image

Comment: Have you tried adding a `DoEvents` statement immediately after you enter the `Do While` loop? It's usually used to enable interaction with "other things" while a tight loop is being executed, but it might loosen things up in this case, too. Details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468), and be sure to read the "Problems Associated with DoEvents" section near the end of that article.

Comment: @GordThompson Hi Gord - apologies for late reply, been busy! Read the article and it was a good read - I've supplied an answer, though not but still progress has been made! Thanks

Comment: @GordThompson Just be careful with `DoEvents`, because it isn't reliable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I couldn't find a way to visually prevent interaction with the GUI once the animation has started. I said visually because it is possible to click buttons and enter input while the animation is running.

It involved the use of the `DoEvents` command which acts as a way of multitasking in MS Access. In mine I added the command above the Do-While loop (see below):

```
'Essentially allow multitasking
DoEvents

Do While coordinates < limit

    coordinates = coordinates + 5

    'Move the image
    Me.imgBean.Move coordinates
    Form.Repaint

Loop
```

It should be noted that it didn't work when I placed it in the Do-While loop. So, when I started the animation by clicking on the image I could still press the other buttons because I entered a value one one field and clicked a button to convert it to another - while the animation is running.

The only question is how to do this in a visual sense.

Comment: As I've said above, `DoEvents` isn't really reliable, so be careful when using it and be sure the application can still work without it. If you want to give the OS a little bit more time, you could loop on `DoEvents` (if it really helps, because in some case it just does nothing).